# Using Custom designed modal box with ASP.NET form controls in Bootstrap Fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I am working on Bootstrap Fullcalendar. I want to create a modal box in which if patient is registered in our database he will check the registered check box and will enter patient MRN. If he is not registered he will fill textboxes to register himself and this will be done through modalbox.

When user click on specific date box in calendar First user will verify his/her registration then he/she will add his appointment with doctor.

For now I have default code of calender

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function ($) {

        /* initialize the calendar
        -----------------------------------------------------------------*/
        var date = new Date();
        var d = date.getDate();
        var m = date.getMonth();
        var y = date.getFullYear();

        var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
            //isRTL: true,
            buttonHtml: {
                prev: '<i class="ace-icon fa fa-chevron-left"></i>',
                next: '<i class="ace-icon fa fa-chevron-right"></i>'
            },

            header: {
                left: 'prev,next today',
                center: 'title',
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
            },
            events: [
              {
                  title: 'All Day Event',
                  start: new Date(y, m, 1),
                  className: 'label-important'
              },
              {
                  title: 'Long Event',
                  start: moment().subtract(5, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                  end: moment().subtract(1, 'days').format('YYYY-MM-DD'),
                  className: 'label-success'
              },
              {
                  title: 'Some Event',
                  start: new Date(y, m, d - 3, 16, 0),
                  allDay: false,
                  className: 'label-info'
              }
            ]
            ,
            editable: true,
            droppable: true, // this allows things to be dropped onto the calendar !!!
            drop: function (date, allDay) { // this function is called when something is dropped

                // retrieve the dropped element's stored Event Object
                var originalEventObject = $(this).data('eventObject');
                var $extraEventClass = $(this).attr('data-class');


                // we need to copy it, so that multiple events don't have a reference to the same object
                var copiedEventObject = $.extend({}, originalEventObject);

                // assign it the date that was reported
                copiedEventObject.start = date;
                copiedEventObject.allDay = allDay;
                if ($extraEventClass) copiedEventObject['className'] = [$extraEventClass];

                // render the event on the calendar
                // the last `true` argument determines if the event "sticks" (http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_rendering/renderEvent/)
                $('#calendar').fullCalendar('renderEvent', copiedEventObject, true);

                // is the "remove after drop" checkbox checked?
                if ($('#drop-remove').is(':checked')) {
                    // if so, remove the element from the "Draggable Events" list
                    $(this).remove();
                }

            }
            ,
            selectable: true,
            selectHelper: true,
            select: function (start, end, allDay) {

                bootbox.prompt("New Event Title:", function (title) {
                    if (title !== null) {
                        calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
                            {
                                title: title,
                                start: start,
                                end: end,
                                allDay: allDay,
                                className: 'label-info'
                            },
                            true // make the event "stick"
                        );
                    }
                });
                calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
            }
            ,
            eventClick: function (calEvent, jsEvent, view) {

                //display a modal
                var modal =
                '<div class="modal fade">\
                  <div class="modal-dialog">\
                   <div class="modal-content">\
                     <div class="modal-body">\
                       <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" style="margin-top:-10px;">&times;</button>\
                       <form class="no-margin">\
                          <label>Change event name &nbsp;</label>\
                          <input class="middle" autocomplete="off" type="text" value="' + calEvent.title + '" />\
                         <button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-check"></i> Save</button>\
                       </form>\
                     </div>\
                     <div class="modal-footer">\
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" data-action="delete"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-trash-o"></i> Delete Event</button>\
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="ace-icon fa fa-times"></i> Cancel</button>\
                     </div>\
                  </div>\
                 </div>\
                </div>';


                var modal = $(modal).appendTo('body');
                modal.find('form').on('submit', function (ev) {
                    ev.preventDefault();

                    calEvent.title = $(this).find("input[type=text]").val();
                    calendar.fullCalendar('updateEvent', calEvent);
                    modal.modal("hide");
                });
                modal.find('button[data-action=delete]').on('click', function () {
                    calendar.fullCalendar('removeEvents', function (ev) {
                        return (ev._id == calEvent._id);
                    })
                    modal.modal("hide");
                });

                modal.modal('show').on('hidden', function () {
                    modal.remove();
                });
            }
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Downvoted for rolling back good edits. Please do not engage in this sort of behaviour. Flagged for moderator attention.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create multiple div. Play with Display property by hide and show the div.

Comment: This problem is resolved now. and its been a year! Thanks for Answer. Let me vote for showing interest.